# Configuration of two-way SSL

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, iis, certificate

I am trying to configure 2 way SSL.  I am getting

```
'Client certificate is required.  No certificate was found in the request.  This might be because the client certificate could not be successfully validated by the operating system or IIS.  For information on how to bypass those validations and use a custom X509CertificateValidator in WCF please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=208540.'
```

in WCF trace log.

On client app I get error 
**"The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'."**

WCF is hosted in IIS and uses wildcard certificate '*.mySite.com'

My WCF web.config:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MySslServiceBehavior">

          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="16777216" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />

            <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Wcfproject.Util.MyServiceAuthorizationManager, MyProjectName"/>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="*.mySite.com" 
                                x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
                                storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root"
                                />
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
            </clientCertificate>            
          </serviceCredentials>

        </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>          

            <binding name="2WaySecureBinding">
              <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"></transport>          
              </security>
            </binding>

    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>     

<services>

      <service behaviorConfiguration="MySslServiceBehavior" name="MyServiceName">             
        <!--2 way SSL-->
        <endpoint bindingNamespace="http://myNamespace/V1" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="2WaySecureBinding" name="httpsBinding" contract="MyServiceName"/>   

      </service>
 </services>
```

My client config:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://2wayWcfProject.mySite.com/MyServiceName.svc" binding="customBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="httpsBinding" contract="MyServiceReference.MyServiceName" behaviorConfiguration="CustomBehavior"
        name="httpsBinding" />
</client>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
        <clientCredentials>
          <clientCertificate findValue="*.ClientSite.com" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root" />
        </clientCredentials>
      </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>


 <bindings>     
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="httpsBinding">
      <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
          requireDerivedKeys="true" includeTimestamp="true" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
        <localClientSettings detectReplays="false" />
        <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" />
      </security>
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
      <httpsTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>

</bindings>
```

I have exported client site certificate '*.ClientSite.com' as .pfx and added/imported it to to trusted certificates on Server (mmc.exe) -> Certificates (local computer) in 'Personal' and 'Trusted Root Certification Authorities'.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I have the same problem...

Comment: I found the solution in the end. I am sorry I cannot help-post configuration because in the meantime I changed jobs and do not have the implementation.